# Removing extra spaces from a sentence having special characters in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, c-strings

I have a sentence:

```
    irmovq   $5    ,     %r1
```

I want to convert it into:

```
irmovq $5, %r1
```

That is, I want to remove extra spaces from this string.
What is the best way to implement such trim function?

Comment: "remove extra spaces from this string" --> why  no space between `"$5"` and `","`?  Unless your rules for re-moving spaces is more complex.  Best to explain all the rules.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The string is the assembly language instruction of Y96-64 instruction set. So there cannot be space between `"$5"` and `"%r1"`. But there can be any amount of spaces between an instruction and a comma and vice-versa, or between two instructions.

Comment: Srijan, OK, if [assembly language instruction of Y96-64 instruction set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61397460/removing-extra-spaces-from-a-sentence-having-special-characters-in-c?noredirect=1#comment108641480_61397460) is a requirement of the question, list all such requirements there.  Else you get an answer like below, which is missing your unstated requirement until now. Then another requirements comes out, then another, ....

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void remove_extra_spaces(char* str) {
  int i, x;
  for(i=x=0; str[i]; ++i)
    if(!isspace(str[i]) || (i > 0 && !isspace(str[i-1])))
      str[x++] = str[i];
  str[x] = '\0';
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  char str[] = "    irmovq   $5    ,     %r1";
  remove_extra_spaces(str);
  printf("%s\n",str);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is a space before comma.

Comment: It's also more conventional to use `str` as a pointer here and advance that in the loop, but this is a nice first-pass.

Comment: I suspect `remove_extra_spaces()` may leave one trailing spaces.  Try `"^^irmovq^^$5^^,^^%r1^^"` where `^` is a space.

Comment: Suggest sentinels to help see leading/trailing space `printf("<%s>\n",str);`